# React js: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-router, react-thunk

I tried to figure out what the error is, but I couldn't overcome it. Below are the error and the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { rootReducer } from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import firebaseConfig from './config/fbConfig';


const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
    reduxFirestore(firebaseConfig), 
    reactReduxFirebase(firebaseConfig)
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
     Module../src/index.js
     D:/New folder/JAVASCRIPT/React/reactJS/myProjects/NINJA APP/ninja-app/src/index.js:17
    `
     14 | 
     15 | const store = createStore(rootReducer,
     16 |   compose(
     > 17 |     applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
     18 |     reduxFirestore(firebaseConfig), 
     19 |     reactReduxFirebase(firebaseConfig)
     20 |   )
    
    `
```

Comment: Ciao, have you tried to put Provider in App.js file and not in index.js?

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

> If you use v3.x.x, There is some **version migration issue** between v2.x.x and v3.x.x

### Answer

As far as I research for you. There is some migration between `react-redux-firebase` v2.x.x and v3.x.x. I attach this reference and hope it is helpful to you :)

And if it is not helpful to you, just comment to me!

### Refrence

01.[v2.*.* to v3.*.* Migration Guide](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html)